# Form won't send data to php page anyway

Tags: html

I have been looking in this forum for a question about the subject I'm posting about here, but I have not found the solution neither here nor anywere on Internet. I have found something like what I'm posting here, but the solution didn't meet my needs. I'm trying to send a form via post to a page specified on an action form, but the $_POST variable is simply sent empty, no matter what server the action page is hosted. I will send the form code to see if any of you have the solution to my problem, or if any of you can identify the error in the code.

```html
<form name='enquete' method='post' action='http://www.webenquetes.com.br/enquete.php?ide=22'>
    <input type='hidden' name='pollcode' value='@|tÜ¸?ÆÛ?â'>
    <div id='idPergunta'><div class='lab'></div><div class='c'><input type='hidden' name='idPergunta1' value='24' size='' maxlength=''   /></div>
    </div><div id='cd_enquete'><div class='lab'></div><div class='c'><input type='hidden' name='cd_enquete1' value='22' size='' maxlength=''   /></div>
    </div><div id='pergunta' class='item'><div class='lab'></div><div class='c'><input type='hidden' name='pergunta1' value='Você é a favor de que o comércio de maconha seja legal?'/>Você é a favor de que o comércio de maconha seja legal?</div>
    </div><div id='multipla_resposta'><div class='lab'></div><div class='c'><input type='hidden' name='multipla_resposta1' value='0' size='' maxlength=''   /></div>
    </div><div class='form2' id='form2_0'><div id='idResposta1_0'><div class='lab'></div><div class='c'><input type='hidden' name='idResposta1_0' value='112' size='' maxlength='' /></div>
    </div>
    
    <div id='cd_pergunta1_0'><div class='lab'></div><div class='c'><input type='hidden' name='cd_pergunta1_0' value='24' size='' maxlength='' /></div>
    </div>
    
    <div id='resposta1_0' class='item'><div class='lab'></div><div class='c'><input type='radio' name='resposta1_' value='Sim.' size='50' maxlength='1024' onclick='functionAnswer(0, 0);'/> Sim.</div>
    </div>
    
    </div><div class='form2' id='form2_1'><div id='idResposta1_1'><div class='lab'></div><div class='c'><input type='hidden' name='idResposta1_1' value='113' size='' maxlength=''  /></div>
    </div><div id='cd_pergunta1_1'><div class='lab'></div><div class='c'><input type='hidden' name='cd_pergunta1_1' value='24' size='' maxlength=''  /></div>
    </div><div id='resposta1_1' class='item'><div class='lab'></div><div class='c'><input type='radio' name='resposta1_' value='Não.' size='50' maxlength='1024' onclick='functionAnswer(0, 1);' /> Não.</div>
    </div></div><div id='botao_votar'><input type='submit' name='votar' value='Votar' /></div></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, and I will share the solution with you. There was nothing wrong with the form above. The error was in the page specified in its property action (enquete.php). This page contains an iframe tag whose source is 'enq.php', and this is the page that should be receiving the data from the form above and storing them in its variable $_POST. Today I discovered that the variable $_POST was indeed retrieving the data from the form correctly, but it was happening only in the page 'enquete.php' which means that the values of the variable $_POST cannot be transfered to the variable $_POST in a page specified in an iframe tag source. I'm sharing this to help people know more about web developping and avoid commiting mistakes related to server variables and the use of iframe tag.

Comment: If you want the variables available within the iFrame (not always a good idea), append them to the iFrame URL, and access them with $_GET.  eg: http://example.com/enq.php?var1=DATA&var2=DATA2

Comment: If its not sensitive data, and its validated that the data sent is comming from the right user (eg: not allow someone to change it and see information from other person or register information as someone else) then its a good alternative. Other alternatives for exchanging information between the iframe and the main frame are localstorage and accessing through the window objects of both entities using javascript